# How to terminate websphere app server instance from wsadmin?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, ibm-was

I have a jython script which stops and starts a websphere application server v7 instance. I normally use AdminControl.stopServer command for the stopping, but sometimes the instance gets hung up, and the request thread times out. Then I have to terminate the instance from the web console. Is there a way to make the instance "terminate" immediately, rather than wait for a graceful stop ? I basically want the web console terminate button functionality in wsadmn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command assistance says:

AdminControl.invoke('WebSphere:name=NodeAgent,process=nodeagent,platform=common,node=node1,diagnosticProvider=true,version=8.5.5.2,type=NodeAgent,mbeanIdentifier=NodeAgent,cell=ndcell,spec=1.0', 'terminate', '[server1]', '[java.lang.String]')

Comment: I had completely forgotten about the command assiastance. Thanks for reminding me. I have added my functions in the answer if it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getNodeNameForServer(serverName):
    nodes = AdminConfig.list("Node").split("\n")
    for node in nodes:
        nodeServers = AdminConfig.list("Server", node).split("\n")
        for nodeServer in nodeServers:
            sname = AdminConfig.showAttribute(nodeServer, "name")
            if sname == serverName:
                nname = AdminConfig.showAttribute(node, "name")
                return nname
    return 'NONE'

def terminateServer(serverName):
    nodeName=getNodeNameForServer(serverName)
    if (nodeName != "NONE"): 
        print '\nTerminating server: %s\n' % (serverName)
        nodeAgentObj=AdminControl.completeObjectName('type=NodeAgent,node='+nodeName+',*')
        print AdminControl.invoke(nodeAgentObj, 'terminate', '['+serverName+']', '[java.lang.String]')
```